# golang http helloworld doesn't block

Tags: http, go

My code is just the same as in [gowiki](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

However, after I build and run this program, it exit immediately without blocking so that I get no response when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/monkey` from Chrome.

Environment: Ubuntu 14(in VirtualBox on Windows7)

Why?

Comment: Do you have anything else using port 8080? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the error returned from `ListenAndServe`

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`http.ListenAndServe` function returns an object that conforms `error` interface. If the call does not block, it definitely means that some kind of error has happened. The most popular are:

- there is already another process listening that port
- your user has no right to bind socket on port `8080`, or `0.0.0.0` interface

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a `permission denied` error. Using `sudo` worked like a charm.

```
sudo go run filename.go
```

or

```
sudo filename
```